# Can you explain the behavior of this Go pointer manipulation?

Tags: go, variable-assignment

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Item struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    var items []*Item
    item := Item{}
    items = append(items, &item)
    x := items[0]
    y := *x
    x.val++
    fmt.Printf("x=%v, y=%v\n", *x, y)
}
```

This prints:

```
x={1}, y={0}
```

I can't understand why the values are different. `x` is a pointer to the 1st element in the array, and we increment the `val` field using `x`, then the 1st element has been changed. `y` is the first element, and its `val` should've changed too, but didn't? If, however, the `y := *x` statement is moved to after `x.val++`, then the values are equal. Why?

Comment: You are dereferencing before assigning to `y`, so `y` holds a copy of the original value pointed by `x`. Mutating `x` doesn't affect `y`

Comment: `y := *x` makes a copy of `*x`, a copy of the first Item. That copy is not changed magically if you change the source of this copy.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/68695937/4108803

Comment: because x is a pointer to item object so any change in x will change item object but y is a copy of item object..y is not a pointer to item object. x.val++ is chaging item object.

Comment: @blackgreen In my case, it seems dereferencing makes a copy, which, to me, is clearer than assignment makes a copy (link you referred to). I mean, `i := 1`, `j := i`, I'd not expect `j` to see the changes in `i`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar dereferencing does not make a copy, in itself. Variable initialization does. The fact that you are assigning to `y` the dereferenced value implies that `y` will hold a copy to whatever was pointed to, hence "disconnecting" `y` from `x` original value. If you assign `x` to `y` without deref, `y` will hold a copy of the pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only this line needs to be explained

`y := *x`

and it means to take value from this pointer (`*x`) and assign it to `y`, now `y` has a freshly non connected to `x` value.

Answer (score -2):

Because `x` is already a pointer to a Item. Try just `y := x`

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. `x` is a ptr is already stated in the question, so, you're merely stating the obvious. The comments and the accepted answer explain the behavior shown more clearly.