# Is ++ syntactic sugar for += 1?

Tags: go

As far as I understand, indexing a map returns a copy of the map value. With this in mind, consider the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{"xxx": 100}
    m["xxx"]++
    fmt.Println(m["xxx"]) // prints 101
}
```

The code above prints `101`, whereas I expected `100`.
My reasoning is that `m["xxx"]` returns *a copy of the value* assigned to the key `"xxx"` (i.e., `100`), and the operator `++` increments this copy of the value but this doesn't affect the original value stored in the map – only the copy changes.

However, considering that we assign a value to a map key by putting the key within brackets and using `=` to specify the value (i.e., `m[key] = value`). Then, if `m["xxx"]++` were translated to `m["xxx"] += 1` by the compiler – which is, in turn, equivalent to `m["xxx"] = m["xxx"] + 1` – this would explain the result of the code above.

My question is whether the increment operator (`++`) is syntactic sugar for the by-one addition assignment (`+= 1`). Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: I believe ++ is in every language, where it exists, syntax sugar for +=1.

Comment: @TheFool Not in C++; `++` and `+=` are operators that can be overloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language specification says that the ++/-- operators should work with a map index expression as the operand.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#IncDec_statements

> The "++" and "--" statements increment or decrement their operands by
> the untyped constant 1. As with an assignment, the operand must be
> addressable **or a map index expression**.

*How* that functionality should be implemented is not specified and may therefore be different across different compilers or different versions of the same compiler.

---

If you search the `cmd/compile/internal` directory of your Go installation, which is the source code of the Go compiler if I'm not mistaken, you'll find a number of lines that seem to confirm your guess. I have nowhere near enough knowledge about the code to provide a conclusive answer however.

Examples: [one](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/042548b1fdba21e351368e9f3ecd93059d09083f/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax/parser.go#L2157-L2161) and [two](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/042548b1fdba21e351368e9f3ecd93059d09083f/src/cmd/compile/internal/noder/helpers.go#L300-L314)

And the `gccgo` implementation of the spec, which I've never looked at, may or may not do the IncDec the same way.

Answer (score 2):

*"My reasoning is that m["xxx"] returns a copy of the value"* — I don't think this is a fair assumption. The specs under [index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions) only say the following:

> A primary expression of the form `a[x]` **denotes the element** of the [...] map `a` indexed by `x`

and

> if the map contains an entry with key `x`, `a[x]` **is the map element with key `x`**

The verbs "denotes" and "is" arguably do not imply a copy. A copy is made [only when you assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695937) the result of the index expression to a variable.

The map index expression is simply not addressable, so that you can't memory alias the values stored in the map.

As for whether the increment operator `++` is syntactic sugar for `+= 1` or not, the specs explicitly [state that](https://go.dev/ref/spec#IncDec_statements):

> The following assignment statements are **semantically equivalent**:

```
IncDec statement    Assignment
x++                 x += 1
x--                 x -= 1
```

So `op++` has the same meaning of `op += 1`, and `a[x]++` increments the operand `a[x]` which "denotes/is" the map element with key `x`.